# Using Ubuntu 23.10, android emulator fails to start

Tags: android, linux

`emulator @Pixel_8_API_VanillaIceCream`

After running the command above, the emulator fails to start and below are the logs

```
❯ emulator @Pixel_8_API_VanillaIceCream -log-nofilter
INFO    | Storing crashdata in: /tmp/android-jonakote/emu-crash-34.1.19.db, detection is enabled for process: 5210
INFO    | Android emulator version 34.1.19.0 (build_id 11525734) (CL:N/A)
INFO    | Found systemPath /home/jonakote/DevTools/android_sdk/system-images/android-VanillaIceCream/google_apis_playstore/x86_64/
INFO    | Storing crashdata in: /tmp/android-jonakote/emu-crash-34.1.19.db, detection is enabled for process: 5210
WARNING | Host CPU is missing the following feature(s) required for x86_64 emulation: SSSE3 SSE4.1 SSE4.2
WARNING | Hardware-accelerated emulation may not work properly!
INFO    | Info: Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway. ((null):0, (null))
Fontconfig warning: "/usr/share/fontconfig/conf.avail/05-reset-dirs-sample.conf", line 6: unknown element "reset-dirs"
library_mode host gpu mode host
Initializing hardware OpenGLES emulation supportandroid_startOpenglesRenderer: gpu infoI0329 16:08:08.612522    5210 HealthMonitor.cpp:279] HealthMonitor disabled.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I was expecting the emulator to boot up.
Tried using from Terminal and Android Studio

Comment: What physical CPU are you running on: `WARNING | Host CPU is missing the following feature(s) required for x86_64 emulation: SSSE3 SSE4.1 SSE4.2`

Comment: This is the model name from running lscpu;  AMD A4-3400 APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics

Comment: That CPU appears to be old (>10 yrs). Go through https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#vm-linux to see if you can enable virtualization. If you are unable to run a emulator (can't run or too slow), use a physical device for debugging.